# How to change table B value(include from table A) to 0 if the value that include from table A get delete

Tags: php, mysql

How to solve this problem (mysql table): What PHP code or MySQL that I need to use `(when I delete adminid = 1 from table A, the value of adminid table B should change to 0)`? Is it possible?

Table A has:

```
adminid = 1
adminname = jack
```

Table B has:

```
newsid = 1
adminid = 1
```

The `TableB.adminid` should change to `0` if `TableA.adminid = 1` gets deleted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through PHP and MySql it's possible if the adminid is not a foreign key in table B (In relationship with table A). Instead of 0 you can make it to null using mysql. There is a SQL command you need to use to enable it: `ON DELETE SET NULL`. 
[Refer this for more detail](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete_null.php)

Comment: so i need to give not null and costraint to it ?

Comment: No, You need make it nullable column. If you apply the not null constraint it will raise error.

Comment: will that null be eror when i echo it on php ? or it will be just blank like "    "

Comment: It won't give any error, It will be empty. In your database it's show as null

Comment: Happy To help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL triggers to set the desired value for `table_b.adminid` when `table_a.adminid` is changed. You can create your own functions and procedures as well in the triggers to set desired value on conditions.

For e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (adminid INT, adminname VARCHAR(255));
CREATE TABLE table_b (newsid INT, adminid INT);

CREATE TRIGGER delete_adminid AFTER DELETE ON table_a
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE table_b SET adminid = 0 WHERE adminid = OLD.adminid;
    END;
```

The above trigger will set `table_b.adminid = 0` after any delete action on `table_a`.

Using triggers you do not need to write any back-end code. Every change is handled by database server. Also, you can write triggers before/after `INSERT`, `UPDATE` actions as well.

References:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: can you give example ? i dont get it , sorry still newbie at mysql

Comment: @RickyWijaya I have updated my answer above, you can see an example.

Comment: Thanks its more simple then before